# Run commands on a different computer

Tags: windows, backup, remote-control

Here's the situation:
I have one server and two terminals. I want to run a semi-automatic backup that will be run on one of the terminals, which will, obviously, back up some files, etc. However, one of the commands which the back up should do is run a shell command that should be ran at the server (sql server command). How can I run a command on the server from the terminal?

Right now I'm using batchrun for the backup, running it from a vnc on the server.

**EDIT**: They're all Windows machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SysInternals PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). It allows you to remotely execute files on any Windows system you have administrator credentials for. You could add a psexec command to the batch file (or whatever you're using) on the terminal which will then run the desired commands on the server.